# WebSphere Scripting : AdminTask.createAuthDataEntry(...) : java.sql.SqlException: Login failed for user ''

Tags: scripting, websphere, wsadmin

I'm having a problem with WebSphere 8.0

I create an ID by typing this into the Jython wsadmin console:

```
AdminTask.createAuthDataEntry(['-alias', 'uni', '-user', 'uni', '-password', 'uni', '-description', 'uni/uni'])
AdminConfig.save()
```

I type this:

```
AdminTask.listAuthDataEntries()
```

and notice:

```
'[[alias Unica9100/uni] [userId uni] [description uni] [_Websphere_Config_Data_Id cells/UnicaVMNode03Cell|security.xml#JAASAuthData_1401128477833] [_Websphere_Config_Data_Type JAASAuthData] [password *******] ]'
```

I go to the JAAS2 alias page and it's listed there.

I go to a datasource and select it for the auth alias.

I test connection.

I get this error:

```
[5/26/14 14:23:59:621 EDT] 0000001b SystemErr     R java.sql.SQLException: Login failed for user ''. ClientConnectionId:3b59e5a5-ac1c-4049-aa58-c245886b5918 DSRA0010E: SQL State = S0001, Error Code = 18,456 
[5/26/14 14:23:59:621 EDT] 0000001b SystemErr     R     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
```

- **Notice the SQL exception says the login name is '' -- for some reason it's blank.**
- I go back to the JAAS2 auth page.
- I resave the credential without any modifications.
- I test the connection again.
- It works.
- What am I missing?

Comment: Are you using the Single Server topology, or a Network Deployment topology?

Comment: I'm using WebSphere Network Deployment edition, but I've just got each profile configured a single simple AppServer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server needs to be restarted for this change to be reflected when it is only done through Admin Scripting.

Comment: Yes, calling the save() API was indeed not enough. The application server had to be forcibly rebooted for the changes to take effect.