# Finalize wsadmin script task "createAuthDataEntry"

Tags: scripting, websphere, wsadmin

I have a follow-up question to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23876382/6704379): is it possible to finalize the AdminTask.createAuthDataEntry task in one wsadmin script?

I need to invoke this task so that WAS can establish a connection to a datasource that I have defined in the same script.

Defining an auth entry from the web console does not require a restart. Typically I would not expect that a restart would be required for authentication changes.

I have tried to use the task `AdminControl.invoke(AdminControl.queryNames('WebSphere:*,type=Server,node=%s,process=%s' % ('node', 'server')), 'restart')` inside the script, but this stops the instance without booting it up again. Also, I cannot verify the datasource connection within the same script because of these limitations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating or modifying authentication data entries from wsadmin requires a server restart.  We have an [RFE](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=viewChangeRequest&CR_ID=70158) to allow wsadmin to make dynamic updates to them without a server restart which you can vote for.  In order to stop and start your server using wsadmin, it's probably easiest for the OS-level (bat or sh) script that invokes wsadmin to call two scripts.